# Could not load file or assembly 'mysql.web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]Here i am creating login page to check validateUSer but i got exception: Here i posted my full code please check it once...

enter code here

namespace Loginusingmvc.Controllers
 {
   public class LoginController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Login/

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl = "")
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return LogOut();
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

// [HttpPost]
public  bool ValidateUser(string UserID, string Password)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
        return false;

    using (ntc_salesEntities context = new ntc_salesEntities())
    {
        var user = (from u in context.user_master
                    where String.Compare(u.UserID, UserID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                          && String.Compare(u.Password, Password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();

        return user != null;
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(user_master model, string returnUrl = "")
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserID,model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserID,false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }

    }
    return View(model);

}


public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

}

```
    Route:

   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default1",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = 
              UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Html

```
    @model Loginusingmvc.Models.user_master

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>LogIn</h2>


    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed, check details")

<div>
       @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
        {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.UserID)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Password)</div>
        <div  class="editor-field">@Html.PasswordFor(u=> u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.Password)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="Login" />

    </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

web.config

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Loginusingmvc-20140516104010;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Loginusingmvc-20140516104010.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LoginEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Login.csdl|res://*/Models.Login.ssdl|res://*/Models.Login.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=206.225.85.212;user id=ntc;password=NTC@123;database=ntc_sales&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="ntc_salesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=;user id=ntc;password=NTC@123;database=ntc_sales&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="DAConnection" connectionString="Data Source=;user id=;database=" providerName="MySql.Data.MySQLClient" />
```

```
   <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" 
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,mysql.web" connectionStringName="DAConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         passwordFormat="Hashed"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" 
         />
  </providers>
</membership>

  <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection"
        applicationName="/"
        name="MySqlRoleProvider"
        type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, mysql.web"
        autogenerateschema="true"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>


<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add type="MySql.Web.Security.MySqlProfileProvider, mysql.web"
          name="MySqlProfileProvider"
          applicationName="/"
          connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection"
          autogenerateschema="true"/>
    <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
  </providers>
</profile>
```

Comment: add reference to mysql.web.dll and make sure mysql connector is installed on server if working on localhost on system also should have mysql connector

Comment: i need to download and add the .dll file?

Comment: i added the reference for my application version(6.8.3.0)

Comment: you need to install mysqlconnector and in its installation location there will be dll mysql.web.dll add reference to it

Comment: in the solution explorer in project references check mysql.web.dll is there?

Comment: yes i added reference still not working

Comment: connector is installed?

Comment: from this link i installed and i  repaired also http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad (add reference to mysql.web.dll and make sure mysql connector is installed on server) server means database server?

Comment: no the server on which application is running

Comment: so i am working on my pc with remote database and only i install in my pc is it fine?

Comment: i think so it should in my case my db and app server were same so it was also installed on the server as well but i am not sure

Comment: if i add the system.web.dll in bin folder of my application it's showing error like this  "Could not load type 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' from assembly 'mysql.web'."

Comment: you just need to add reference on references and connector installed and it should work

Comment: yes i done both i am sure and i had given link to which i had downloaded also but still same errors

Comment: hmm, then i can't figure out why its not working for you

Comment: on thing make sure verion match in web.config and dll reference added

Comment: where to add version in web.config?  type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider,mysql.web,Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"

Answer (score 0):

Need modify the assemblydependency

```
enter code here  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```